# Oracle SQL - loop through unique values in one column to concatenate values from a second column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like this one

```
ID _______ LEN
PK01       10
PK01       20
PK01       30
PK05       10
PK05       70
PK11       50
PK11       70
PK11       110
PK11       150
```

I want to write a query that will return results like this:

```
ID _______ LEN
PK01       10, 20, 30
PK05       10, 70
PK11       50, 70, 110, 150
```

NOTES ON DATA:

- As above, in my table `ID`s can be ordered but there are gaps between `ID`s

  As above, `ID:LEN` is a `1:many` relationship

  As above, different `ID`s can have a record with the same `LEN` value(s).

  The table is reference data. Each `ID:LEN` combination constitutes 1 unique row. Neither field is nullable.

NOTE ON RESULTS:

This will be for a report (data extract).

The `ALL LENS` can be a concatenation of `TO_CHAR(LEN) values`.

I write a lot of SQL select statements. I'm just struggling with going to the next level: how to loop through `ID`s to concatenate `LEN` values for each `ID` group.

Comment: Hint:  `LISTAGG()`.

Comment: Always include your database *version*, such as 11.2.0.4 or 12.2.0.1. Run `select banner from v$version` and see the first row in the output. Different tools are available depending on your version.

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays, `LISTAGG` would be your choice:

```
SQL> with test (id, len) as
  2    (select 'PK01', 10 from dual union all
  3     select 'PK01', 20 from dual union all
  4     select 'PK01', 30 from dual union all
  5     select 'PK05', 10 from dual union all
  6     select 'PK05', 70 from dual
  7    )
  8  select id,
  9         listagg(len, ', ') within group (order by len) len
 10  from test
 11  group by id
 12  order by id;

ID   LEN
---- ------------------------------
PK01 10, 20, 30
PK05 10, 70

SQL>
```

If your database version doesn't support it (or the result exceeds 4000 characters), see whether `XMLAGG` helps:

```
SQL> with test (id, len) as
  2    (select 'PK01', 10 from dual union all
  3     select 'PK01', 20 from dual union all
  4     select 'PK01', 30 from dual union all
  5     select 'PK05', 10 from dual union all
  6     select 'PK05', 70 from dual
  7    )
  8  select id,
  9         rtrim(xmlagg(xmlelement(e, len ||', ')
 10               order by len).extract ('//text()'), ', ') len
 11  from test
 12  group by id
 13  order by id;

ID   LEN
---- ------------------------------
PK01 10, 20, 30
PK05 10, 70

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your Oracle version is 11.2.x or newer, you can try this:

```
  SELECT ID "ID", LISTAGG(LEN, ', ') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY LEN) "LEN"
    FROM <table_name>
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: nimsraw, that is GORGEOUS. Yes, helped indeed.
Thanks for making my Friday :D